# Unable to read a table in selenium webdriver after Updating to latest webdriver 2.48.2

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Previously i was working on WebDriver 2.45.0 and my script was working fine but after updating it to 2.48.2, i am unable to read content of table even isDisplayed method return false although the table is displayed. 
This is the table tag

```
<table id="tableID" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin-top: 3px; width: 100%; background-color: transparent;" class="grid potable" rules="all" border="1" cellspacing="0">
```

Function to read table content

```
WebElement irTable = driver.findElement(By.id("tableID"));
List<WebElement> rows = irTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

for (int rnum=1;rnum<rows.size();rnum++)  {
   List<WebElement> columns = rows.get(rnum).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
   {columns.get(1).getText()}
}
```

Do i need to switch back to old version or is there any way to solve this.

PS : as per client requirement we had to upgrade Firefox and i started facing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

WebDriver 2.48:
Supports native events for Firefox version 31 (immediately previous
  ESR). Native event support has been discontinued for versions of
  Firefox later than 33. Synthetic events tested on Firefox versions 31
  (immediately previous ESR), 38 (immediately previous release and current
  ESR), and **39 (current release)**

Please refer [Selenium Java Changelog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG) and choose right selenium jar for your testing. Selenium dotnet version is supporting firefox till Firefox 41.

Comment: Thanks i have checked it and as per logs it should work. I am using Firefox 43.0.2 and selenium 2.48.2. The problem is i am able to read another tables but not this one.

Comment: Can you pls provide the link where you checked the logs specifying FF 43 is supported? And most of the time, newer versions are of browsers will work, failures will be noticed for certain elements.

Comment: Also, as per your code `columns.get(1).getText();`  just gets text but not stored or displayed anywhere.  may be the code is reading the value, but you are not handling the read value.

Comment: Thanks, i have just wrote the code like that here but tried storing the value and printing into console but it didn't work.

Comment: But the issue is resolved. dont know how i just cleared all my cookies and tried again and its working fine.